# Darboux intermediate value property theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

According the proof which is based on the extreme value theorem, it seems that we "perfectly guess" the minimum/maximum to be the point we're looking for. Hence, I wonder if there is some intuition behind that guess which can improve my understanding regarding the general idea of the proof rather than its formal approach.

Thanks

The discussed proof is displayed as "Proof 1" below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Please write out the proof you are referring to. Note that there are multiple proofs.

Comment: So I did, thank you.